# Svg не работает анимация в IE11

Tags: reactjs, svg, ie11

не работает анимация в иконке в IE11

```js
  <svg className={className} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="43" height="43" viewBox="0 0 43 43">
      <defs>
        <circle id={circle} cx="139.5" cy="2369.5" r="21.5" />
        <mask id={mask} width="43" height="43" x="0" y="0" fill="#fff" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <use xlinkHref={`#${circle}`} />
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <use fill="none" fillRule="evenodd" stroke="#FFF" strokeDasharray="1 4" strokeWidth="8.4" mask={`url(#${mask})`} transform="translate(-118 -2348)" xlinkHref={`#${circle}`} />
      <g transform="translate(28 30) rotate(180)" className="bars">
        <Bar x={0} h={6} />
        <Bar x={5} h={12} />
        <Bar x={10} h={16} />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: IE11 и animate это не совместимые понятия